# Why is the %IF statement not executing?

Tags: sas

```
%macro SASIsAwful();

        %let LastEnt = 12;
        %let i = 1;
        %do i = 1 %to &LastEnt.;

            proc sql noprint;
                select Diff into :CheckDiff from Trial01 where RowNum = &i.;
                select ACTV_DTM into :CheckDate from Trial01 where RowNum = &i.;
                create table Eval001 as select * from Trial01 where RowNum = &i.;
            quit;

            %if &CheckDiff. = 'N' %then %do; %put &CheckDiff.; %end;
            
        %end;

%mend SASIsAwful;
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the `%if` statement did not work.  `Proc SQL` worked fine, and I manually confirmed that it saved the value `N` into `&CheckDiff.` twelve times.  Yet, for some reason, the `%if` statement never executed, and there was no error message.  What went wrong here?  Thank you.

Comment: Apparently, the `%if` statement works with numerical values, but not characters.  If that's the case, why not show an error message?

Answer (score 1):

The correct macro statement should be

```
%IF &CHECKDIFF = N %then ... ;
```

If you examine an unconditional %put, you will most likely see a log lines such as

```
%put INFO: &=CHECKDIFF;
--- log ---
INFO: CHECKDIFF=N;   
INFO: CHECKDIFF=Y;
```

Answer (score 1):

Richard is right.

Macrovars are always strings.
CheckDiff is just the 1-char-string N, which is different from the 3-char-string "N".

You could also write
%IF "&CHECKDIFF" = "N" %then ...
but not
%IF '&CHECKDIFF' = 'N' %then ...
because Macrovars are only replaced within double quotes, not single quotes.